# How to modernize apache conf virtualhost files

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, conf

So I have some old Apache confs for virtualhosts that I have not updated for awhile, and I would like to review them and modernize them if needed. But I'm not quite sure where to begin or what is the best approach. Is there some kind of linter script or best practice guide with changes perhaps? What would you suggest

Comment: How about the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)?

Comment: That is actually very good! thanks